# Flask wtf Form not submitting and no error feedback

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm new to python flask, My current application have a form that help users update their profile and it will display on the users backend, but after writing every line of codes the codes is not showing error after submitting but i am not getting all the credentials i inputted on the form.

here is the route for profile settings

```
@app.route("/profile/settings", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def profile_settings():
    #education = Education.query.filter_by(user=current_user).first()
    form = UpdateProfileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.aboutme = form.aboutme.data
        current_user.phone = form.phone.data
        current_user.location = form.location.data
        current_user.facebook = form.facebook.data
        current_user.twitter = form.twitter.data
        current_user.linkedin = form.linkedin.data
        current_user.school = form.school.data
        current_user.course = form.course.data
        current_user.fromDate = form.fromDate.data
        current_user.toDate = form.toDate.data
        current_user.description = form.description.data
        current_user.institution = form.institution.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your profile have been updated", "danger")
        return redirect(url_for('profile_settings'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.aboutme.data = current_user.aboutme
        form.phone.data = current_user.phone
        form.location.data = current_user.location
        form.facebook.data = current_user.facebook
        form.twitter.data = current_user.twitter
        form.linkedin.data = current_user.linkedin
        form.school.data = current_user.school
        form.course.data = current_user.course
        form.fromDate.data = current_user.fromDate
        form.toDate.data = current_user.toDate
        form.institution.data = current_user.institution
        form.description.data = current_user.description
    return render_template("profile-settings.html",
                           title="Profile Setting",
                           form=form)
```

and here is the form

```
class UpdateProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    picture = FileField('Change Profile Picture',
                        validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    aboutme = TextAreaField("About Me", validators=[DataRequired()])
    phone = TextField("Phone Number", validators=[DataRequired()])
    location = StringField("Location", validators=[DataRequired()])
    facebook = StringField("Facebook", validators=[DataRequired()])
    twitter = StringField("Twitter", validators=[DataRequired()])
    linkedin = StringField("Linkedin", validators=[DataRequired()])
    school = StringField("School", validators=[DataRequired()])
    institution = StringField("Institution", validators=[DataRequired()])
    course = StringField("Course", validators=[DataRequired()])
    fromDate = DateField("From", validators=[DataRequired()])
    toDate = DateField("To", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Description", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Update")
```

The Html code is here...

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

<!-- To make contents vertically centered -->
<div style="height: 100vh;" class="container">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
            <div class="mx-auto w-75 card p-4 shadow-lg w-sm">

                <!-- Header Logo-->
                <div class="text-center animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-500 logo">Profile <span class="text-danger">Setting</span></h1>

                    <hr class="mt-4">
                </div>

                <!-- Form -->
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

                    <!-- Firstname(fname) and lastname(lname) Input -->
                    <div class="card p-3">
                        <h5 class="border-bottom">
                            About Me
                        </h5>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputAboutMe">Write a paragraph about yourself</label>
                            {% if form.aboutme.errors %}
                            {{ form.aboutme(placeholder="Write a paragraph about yourself", class="form-control is-invalid", rows=7) }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.aboutme.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.aboutme(placeholder="Write a paragraph about yourself", class="form-control", rows=7) }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <!-- Users Phone and Location -->
                    <div class="card p-3">
                        <h5 class="border-bottom">
                            Contact Information
                        </h5>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                            {% if form.phone.errors %}
                            {{ form.phone(placeholder="08012345678", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.phone.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.phone(placeholder="08012345678", class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputLocation">Location</label>
                            {% if form.location.errors %}
                            {{ form.location(placeholder="Your Location", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.location.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.location(placeholder="Your Location", class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <!-- Social Media Accounts (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn) -->
                    <div class="card p-3">
                        <h5 class="border-bottom">
                            Socail Media Info
                        </h5>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputFacebook">Facebook</label>
                            {% if form.facebook.errors %}
                            {{ form.facebook(placeholder="Facebook", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.facebook.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.facebook(placeholder="Facebook", class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputTwitter">Twitter</label>
                            {% if form.twitter.errors %}
                            {{ form.twitter(placeholder="Twitter", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.twitter.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.twitter(placeholder="Twitter", class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputLinkedin">Linkedin</label>
                            {% if form.linkedin.errors %}
                            {{ form.linkedin(placeholder="Linkedin", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.linkedin.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.linkedin(placeholder="Linkedin", class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <!-- Education (School, Institution, Date, Description) Input -->
                    <div class="card p-3">
                        <h5 class="border-bottom">
                            Education
                        </h5>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputSchool">School</label>
                            {% if form.school.errors %}
                            {{ form.school(placeholder="School", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.school.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.school(placeholder="School", class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputSchool">Institution</label>
                            {% if form.institution.errors %}
                            {{ form.institution(placeholder="Univeristy or College", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.institution.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.institution(placeholder="Univeristy or College", class="form-control") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputCourse">Course</label>
                            {% if form.course.errors %}
                            {{ form.course(placeholder="Course", class="form-control is-invalid")}}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.course.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.course(placeholder="Course", class="form-control")}}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                {% if form.fromDate.errors %}
                                {{ form.fromDate(placeholder="From", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.fromDate.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                {% else %}
                                {{ form.fromDate(placeholder="From", class="form-control") }}
                                {% endif %}

                                {% if form.toDate.errors %}
                                {{ form.toDate(placeholder="To", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.toDate.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                {% else %}
                                {{ form.toDate(placeholder="To", class="form-control ml-3") }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-2" for="inputDescription">Description</label>
                            {% if form.description.errors %}
                            {{ form.description(placeholder="Write about your education", class="form-control is-invalid", rows=6) }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.description.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ form.description(placeholder="Write about your education", class="form-control", rows=6) }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <!-- Profile Picture -->
                    <div class="card p-3">
                        <h5 class="border-bottom">
                            Change Profile Picture
                        </h5>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.picture(class="form-control-file") }}
                            {% if form.picture.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.picture.errors %}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span></br>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Update Button -->
                    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary mt-4">Update</button>

                    <hr>

                </form>

                <!-- Flash Messages -->
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
                {% if messages%}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                <div class="mt-3 alert alert-danger rounded text-center text-danger p-3 font-weight-bold"><span
                        class="{{ category }}"></span>{{ message }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and here is the User Model in the database, I'm using SQLalchemy

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    books = db.relationship('Book', backref='user')
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='user')
    uploads = db.relationship('Upload', backref='user.id')

    #Users Personal Details
    aboutme = db.Column(db.String(450), nullable=False, default="No Description")
    phone = db.Column(db.Text(20), nullable=False, default="00000000000")
    location = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, default="Unknown City")

    # User Accounts
    facebook = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    twitter = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    linkedin = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)

    #User Education Qualification
    school = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    institution = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default="University")
    course = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, default="Economics")
    fromDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    toDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(160), nullable=True)

    # User Image Filename
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User'{self.fname}', '{self.lname}', '{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}'"
```

Comment: It looks like the `if` statement in your route doesn't have a condition that deals with failed form validation. The first condition covers what to do if the form passes validation, and the second condition covers GET requests, but both of those are skipped if a POST request is made but a field doesn't pass WTForms validation. Try adding an `else` condition that flashes a message warning the user that one or more fields didn't pass validation.

Comment: I just did as you said, but still not getting any validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code that may be creating this issue. For every field, you are creating two entry points. For example "about me" has two fields that are identical because of the else/if statement. It's the same for all fields, you're duplicating everything.

To catch an error you should really be using a macro. You shouldn't be adding an additional {{ form.fieldname }} to the else/if statement.

I would remove these and see whether it works.

Right now, how does Flask know which field to use when a user submits? When there are two fields to choose from?

Comment: Glad I could help.